# Ref.get returning null

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am learning google app engine with datastore for my next project. I have made a sample app for the same.

Here are the code for entities:

```
@Entity
public class Quote {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Parent @Load
    private Ref<Author> author;

    public Quote() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Author getAuther() {
        return author.get();
    }

    public void setAuther(Author author) {
        this.author = Ref.create(author);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Author {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and I am inserting a Quote using this API

```
 @ApiMethod(
            name = "insert",
            path = "quote",
            httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
    public Quote insert(Quote quote) {
        ofy().save().entity(quote).now();
        return ofy().load().entity(quote).now();
    }
```

When I try to insert a new quote, I get my author.get() as null. I am stuck in this problem from a long time and I am not able to continue learning.

Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough information here. Does the referenced author entity exist in the datastore? Sounds like it does not.

Comment: @stickfigure  Is ofy().save().entity(quote).now() is not supposed to save the author entity in the database?

Comment: @stickfigure "ofy().save().entity(quote).now()" This code is only storing Quote without storing the corresponding Author. If you could explain how we should store an entity having a parent, It would be highly helpful. Thanks.

Comment: There is no cascading delete in the datastore (or Objectify). If you want to save the parent - or any other entity - just save it. Use a transaction to get atomic behavior if that is what you need.

Comment: @stickfigure The problem is solved. While inserting Quote I also have to insert Author after that. All I want to know is that do we need to insert each ref entity separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not inserting Auther before inserting Quote. You can either hide it within the Entity model or you can do it separately in an API call.